# Excel: Separate empty cells from having 0 value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I wanted to know if there is an option that doesn't allow empty number cells to obtain the 0 value when there is a function that takes values from these cells. For example, if I want to add the numerical values of cells A1 (empty) and A2 (=2) and if one of those cells are empty, I don't want the function to return the value 2.

I hope I was clear enough and I am sorry if what I wrote is misleading.
Thank you very much in advance for any given help!

Comment: You can use `ISBLANK()` to test for empty cells before adding.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please share with us what you have already attempted and where you are stuck. It helps if you add your formula to your question.

Comment: I have already used the if, and, or functions to achieve that but I was actually wondering if their is an option to apply to all the numerical cells. Nevertheless, all of your answers work for me. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just check for blanks before running your function -

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:A10)>0,"Blank Detected",SUM(A1:A10))
```

Countblank() counts cells that are empty/blank, so it won't count a `0`, so this checks if any are blank and if so, returns a message, otherwise it runs your function (sum in this example).

---

Per CharlieRB's answer, you can use `or` to check for blanks and for `0` with something like this -

```
=IF(OR(COUNTBLANK(A1:A10)>0,COUNTIF(A1:A10,0)>0),"Blank or Zero Detected",SUM(A1:A10))
```

Comment: I like this solution better than the nested logic tests I used. :-) Does this account for cells with `0` in them rather than blank?

Comment: @CharlieRB now it does both.

Answer (score 1):

Using the logical `IF` and `OR` functions will help you in this case. You can the `IF` statement to look if conditions are met and the `OR` will check if two criteria are met returning either `TRUE` or `FALSE` to the `IF` function.

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(A2)), "", A1+A2)
```

The `OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(A2)` checks to see if `A1` or `A2` are blank. It either one is, then the `IF` statement uses its `[Value if True]` section. In this case nothing, `""`.

If neither `A1` or `A2` are blank, then the `IF` statement moves to the `[Value if False]` section, `A1+A2`, and produces the results.

If you don't want a zero (`0`) in either cell triggering the addition operation, you can exclude them by adding them to the `OR` statement.

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(A2), A1=0, A2=0), "", A1+A2)
```

Comment: This would get pretty long if the selection is more than 5 numbers. Can you use an array in this?

Comment: Didn't go that deep without clarification from the OP. The example given was only the two cells.